# $mdDialog not close

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am having mdDialog in one controller to show details from another controller.when I click the close button, it does not close.

I used both :
         $mdDialog.hide() and $mdDialog.cancel()

Answer (score 0):

re-check all these:

- correct usage of $mdDialog API:

### ```js
$mdDialo.show({
  controller:function($scope,$mdDialog){
    $scope.close = function(){$mdDialog.hide();}
  },
  templateUrl:'some-template.dialog.html'
})
```

correct link from controller to template.

### i.e. if you are using `$scope.close = function(){ ... }`, then your template should look like : `<md-button ng-click=close()>close</md-button>`

and if you are using controller:
`this.close = function(){...}`
then you need to add a controllerAs in your `$mdDialog.show()` config object:
`controllerAs:'$ctrl'`

and in your template:
`<md-button ng-click=$ctrl.close()></md-button>`